# Is there any specific reason behind Kamal hassan not acting with Roja?

Tags: acting-career, indian-cinema

[Kamal Hassan](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0352032/?ref_=nv_sr_1) has acted with all top heroines in the Kollywood. But, he did not do a single film with one of the top heroine of 90's, Roja.

Is there any specific reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [tupaki.com](http://www.tupaki.com/politicalnews/article/When-Roja-targeted-Kamal-and-Rajini-/34388)

> Speaking in a interview, Roja once commented what will Kamal Haasan's
>   films will have other than kissing scenes with heroines and that's the
>   reason she never got the chance to work with the versatile actor.
>
> Roja was once asked what was her feelings working for the first time with Rajinikanth in the movie ‘Ulaipali’ during a media interaction, the actress replied that she was never bothered about heroes and what matters to her is story and director. These remarks have been a sensation in Tamilnadu and the fans of Superstar launched massive protests demanding the makers to sack her from the project. However she didn't regret what she said and completed the film as female lead.

Its clearly showing that her controversial comments are the reason.